# php semi colon delimited, have problems with a conditional

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi: This is my first question... So please be easy on me. :)

I've got most of my problem resolved but can't figure out one little thing... Here is my database structure...

```
RAK 0 ; none ; WCU ; gray ; 20C ; 40C ; grey ; grey ;
RAK 1 ; none ; WCU ; gray ; 20C ; 40C ; grey ; grey ;
RAK 2 ; none ; WCU ; gray ; 20C ; 40C ; red ; red ;
RAK 3 ; none ; ACU; gray ; 20C ; 40C ; red ; red ;
```

Here is my variable structure....

```
<?php

$rack = array();
if (($handle = fopen("status.txt", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
{
    if(substr(trim($data[0]), 0, 3) == 'RAK')
    {
        $board = trim($data[0]);
        $temp = $data[2];
        $rack[ $board ] = $temp;
    }
   }
   fclose($handle);
    }
   ?>
```

What I have are several divs next to each other and they are set to dislay or not. Display is important because when it displays none the divs move next to each other instead of maintaining the gap as when you hide a div.

```
<div class="rack3wcu" style="display: <?php echo $rack['RAK 3']; ?>;">
```

It actually has served me really well but now I got a curve ball with the acu, wcu. This file is spit out from a super computer and normally the python guys will output the direct word i need to echo... but in this case i need to do something different depending on the two choices.

so what I need is if it is ACU then echo none, else it is WCU then send a different echo saying yes, or none actually depending on the toggle...

Listen folks, I'm horrible with conditionals. Can someone help a brother out?

Comment: `ACU`, `WCU` are the possible variable of `$rack['RAK 3']` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "ACU" and "WCU" are not the only possible values:

```
<div class="rack3wcu" style="display: <?php echo ( trim($rack['RAK 3']) == 'ACU') ? 'none' : ( ( trim($rack['RAK 3']) == 'WCU') ? 'block' : ''); ?>;"></div>
                       // Note that in this situation, you have to decide what to echo when the value is not ACU and not WCU ^^^^
```

If "ACU" and "WCU" are the only possible values, this will be enough:

```
<div class="rack3wcu" style="display: <?php echo ( trim($rack['RAK 3']) == 'ACU') ? 'none' : 'block'; ?>;"></div>
```

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their help. I'm going with MazzCris, because it's something I understand almost.... Basically, MazzCris's statement says if the data = ACU write none, if not, write block? When I run it, no matter the WCU or ACU it prints block. Am I missing something? cause this is a perfect answer. I would put yes in the place of block and none where you have it.

Comment: @luvUI there are probably whitespaces in $rack['RAK 3'] value. I've added trim() in the answer to try to solve this

Comment: @luvUI The first example says: "if ACU write none, if WCU write block, if not ACU and not WCU write nothing )"

The second example says: "if ACU write none, else write block"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would want something like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($rack as $rackIdentifier => $rackType) {
    switch ($rackType) {
        case 'WCU':
?>
            <!-- display some html for WCU-->
<?php
            break;
        case 'ACU':
?>
            <!-- display some html for ACU -->
<?php
            break;
        default:
?>
            <!-- display some html for unknown type (not WCU, not ACU) -->
<?php
    }
}
?>
```